# Why JavaScript implicitly stringify the parameter value when using objects as keys?

Tags: javascript

I have been studying some Javascript Interview Questions and the concept behind this specific question's answer is a bit hard to figure out. The output of the following code is 456 instead of 123 and the reason for this behavior stated as "JavaScript implicitly stringify the parameter value when Using Objects as Keys". Can anyone please explain this concept or provide me any resources to study? Thanks in advance.

```js
var a = {};
var b = { key: "b" };
var c = { key: "c" };
a[b] = 123;
a[c] = 456;
console.log(a[b]); // Output is 456
```

Comment: please add `a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object properties are always either strings or Symbols. If you use something that isn't a string or a Symbol as an object property, it's converted to string as though you'd passed it through the `String` function. So your code is effectively:

```
    var a = /* whatever 'a' is, it wasn't in your question until someone else added
               it; I'm guessing they're probably right with `{}`  or similar */;
    var b = {key: "b"};
    var c = {key: "c"};
    a[String(b)] = 123;
// -- ^^^^^^^-^    
    a[String(c)] = 456;
// -- ^^^^^^^-^    
    console.log(a[String(b)]); // Output is 456
// ---------------^^^^^^^-^
```

When you convert an object to string, if it has a `toString` method, that gets called. The `toString` on plain objects returns `"[object Object]"`, so your keys are both `"[object Object]"`, which means your code is effectively:

```
    var a = /* whatever 'a' is */;
    var b = {key: "b"};
    var c = {key: "c"};
    a["[object Object]"] = 123;
// ---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    a["[object Object]"] = 456;
// ---^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    console.log(a["[object Object]"]); // Output is 456
// ---------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

which is why you see 456 instead of 123.

If you want to use an object as a key, use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (ES2015+):

```js
var map = new Map();
var b = {key: "b"};
var c = {key: "c"};
map.set(b, 123);
map.set(c, 456);
console.log(map.get(b)); // 123
console.log(map.get(c)); // 456
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses only strings or symbols as keys. of not on of the both type supplied, it uses `toString` and returns the default value for objects `[object Object]`.

```js
var a = {},
    b = { key: "b" },
    c = { key: "c" };

a[b] = 123;
a[c] = 456;

console.log(a[b]);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response :)

Answer (score 0):

Expecting that you have defined `a` as an object. Now on setting `b` as key it will be

`{"[object Object]":123}` and on doing `a[c]` it will be `{"[object Object]":456}`. Object does not allow duplicate key. So the previous `key` value is overwritten by the latest one

```js
let a = {};
var b = {
  key: "b"
};
var c = {
  key: "c"
};
a[b] = 123;
a[c] = 456;

console.log(a)
console.log(a[b]);
```

If you set another key the previous one will overwrite by the latest

```js
let a = {};
var b = {
  key: "b"
};
var c = {
  key: "c"
};

var d = {
  key: "d"
};
a[b] = 123;
a[c] = 456;
a[d] = 123;

console.log(a)
console.log(a[b]);
```

Comment: Very interesting, like this explanation too :)